# How to select a value in dropdownList automatically after selecting another value in a different DropDownList with select statement in PHP

Tags: php

With reference to the image below, i would be happy if someone could find time to assist me. I want to select Section Location eg Sales Floor which will select the corresponding sectionLocationID and append it onto the small dropdownbox at the right side of the Dropdown inputbox labled Section Location. I am retrieving the values onto the dropdown box with the query: SELECT locationName,locationID FROM locationDetails ORDER BY locationName

Below is the entire code
     //prepare statement
                if($stmt=$sqlcon->prepare("SELECT locationName,locationID FROM locationDetails ORDER BY locationName")){

```
                $stmt->execute();
                //get result
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
            }

            echo  "<select name='clocation' class='input username'>";


            echo '<option placeholder="'.$placeholdergender.'">'.$placeholdergender.'</option>';
            while($row=$result->fetch_row())
            {

                $section=$row['0'];
               // $sectionID=$row['1'];


                echo '<option value="'.$section.'">'.$section.'</option>';

            }
           // echo '<input type="text" value="'.$sectionID.'">';
            echo '</select>';
            echo '<select>';

            echo  "<select name='cID' class='input username'>";

           // echo '<option placeholder="'.$placeholdergender.'">'.$placeholdergender.'</option>';
            while($row=$result->fetch_row())
            {

               // $section=$row['0'];
                 $sectionID=$row['1'];


                echo '<option value="'.$sectionID.'">'.$sectionID.'</option>';

            }
            // echo '<input type="text" value="'.$sectionID.'">';



            echo '</select>';

            echo '<br>';


            ?>
```

[image: how i want to select]

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thank you for your response. Please how are values passed to the variable $defaultSectionID? Basically i want to select the value in the second drop down list from the first selected value. Example as i select sales floor, automatically, the id of sales floor should be displayed in the second box. Thank you.

Comment: Many thanks Ryan. Please do you have any working example of the javascript that does this? I will be happy to get it. Thank you